# Need a regex to find the word "ERROR:", but not match "ERROR: Opening Local File"

Tags: powershell, regex

I'm writing an error checking script with PowerShell to look over Bitvise SFTP logs and alert if there are any errors.  However, I don't want it to alert me on the string "ERROR: Opening Local File" as this is just telling be that the file already exists in the destination, which is expected.  I'm not very good with regex and I can't seem to find the right combination of elements to find errors other than the one that we can ignore.

Example:

```
ERROR: Writing local file  (I want to be alerted to this)
ERROR: Opening local file  (I don't want to be alerted to this)
```

Comment: I think you want to research "negative look ahead", but my Regex isn't up to spec so I can't post an answer.

Comment: i would likely filter 1st for `error:`, and then filter for NOT `: opening`.

Comment: `^ERROR: [^O]`.

Comment: Soo.. "string starts with ERROR: W" ?

Comment: Although it's possible (as per the answers given), this is typically a problem solved otherwise - not by regexes.

Comment: I mean... `< log grep -E "^ERROR:" | grep -ve "Opening local file"`   i know i know.. you said powershell though

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this seems to do what you want - it uses the way that PoSh can apply a regex match to an entire collection. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a sample data set
  when ready to do this for real, replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with a `Get-Content` call.
- sets the wanted pattern
- sets the *unwanted* pattern
- uses chained regex calls to *exclude* the unwanted and then to *include* the wanted
- assigns that to the `$Result` collection
- displays that on screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
ERROR: Writing local file  (I want to be alerted to this)
ERROR: Opening local file  (I do not want to be alerted to this)
INFO: Some other thing
ERROR: Yet another thing
INFO: A thing that is wanted
WARNING: Something that may be wanted
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

$TargetPattern = 'error:'
$NotWantedPattern = ': opening local file'

$Result = $InStuff -notmatch $NotWantedPattern -match $TargetPattern

$Result
```

output ...

```
ERROR: Writing local file  (I want to be alerted to this)
ERROR: Yet another thing
```

Comment: Although technically not a pure regex answer, this is the solution I went with, so I have marked this as the answer.  I wish I could choose both! Thank you!

Comment: @user1212680 - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Bret - Thanks for the neat edit! you will likely want to make the same "fix the hiliting" edit in the Answer by Hackoo. [*grin*]

Answer (score 40):

As @spikey_richie says, you need [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
ERROR: (?!Opening local file)
```

Basically, instead of specifying what you're looking for, you specify what you *don't* want, and wrap that inside `(?!` and `)`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bHkG8f/1)

Comment: Ah.  I was overcomplicating the regex.  This does appear to work. Thanks! Although this did work, I ended up going with Lee's solution.  If I had the ability to choose multiple answers, I would.  Thank you!

Comment: @JJM: you may have prefered the other answer, but to me, this one answers the question you asked more closely and precisely (how to find the lines with the word "ERROR:" but not match "ERROR: opening local file")... So I think it should be the accepted answer (ie, the appropriate answer to the question asked, regardless of what is used in the end by the asker)

Comment: @Glorfindel : maybe put the space within the (?! Opening local file) so that a line without a space after "ERROR:" is also displayed? (the question says to show lines with "ERROR:" (without a space after :)

Comment: @OlivierDulac, I actually initially did mark this as the answer.  But, the hover text to the solution checkmark advises we choose the answer "most helpful in finding our solution."  I chose the other as my solution, so I marked it as the answer.

Comment: My answer may answer the *question* better, but the other answer answered the *problem* better. It makes perfect sense to accept that one, I don't mind at all @JJM. I even got a nice badge for it: https://superuser.com/help/badges/37/populist?userid=442468

Comment: I think it's a fairly common misconception that there are well-defined criteria for acceptance. It's pretty squishy (informal): _Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally [and] they might not change the accepted answer even if a newer, better answer comes along later._  From https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

Something like that should work too : [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bHkG8f/2)

```
$MyString = @'
ERROR: Writing local file  (I want to be alerted to this)
ERROR: Opening local file  (I don't want to be alerted to this)
INFO: Some other thing
ERROR: Yet another thing
INFO: A thing that is wanted
WARNING: NOT a not-wanted thing
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$pattern = 'ERROR: (?!Opening local file).+'
$MyString | %{ [regex]::matches($_,$pattern) } | %{ $_.Groups[0].Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

This situation is similar to those presented in [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html) --- a great read for anyone learning regex. Whie the negative lookahead posted by [Glorfindel](https://superuser.com/users/442468/glorfindel) works well in this case, this technique is easily expandable to multiple exclusions, lookbehinds combined with lookaheads, etc. and still remain readable.
The essence of the trick is to capture all exclusions in the overall match and the desired content in Group 1. For the OP, the regex would look like:

```
'ERROR: Opening local file|(ERROR:.+$)'
```

Sample:
(In working code, `` <Here-string> -Split "`n" ``
would be replaced by:
`Get-Contnet 'c:\Path\To\Error.log'`
)

```
@'
ERROR: Another error
ERROR: Writing local file  (I want to be alerted to this)
ERROR: Opening local file  (I don't want to be alerted to this)
THIS is not an error
'@ -Split "`n" | ForEach {
    $_ -match 'ERROR: Opening local file|(ERROR:.+$)' | out-null
    $matches[1]
}
```

Screen Capture:

```
PS C:\> @'
>> ERROR: Another error
>> ERROR: Writing local file  (I want to be alerted to this)
>> ERROR: Opening local file  (I don't want to be alerted to this)
>> THIS is not an error
>> '@ -Split "`n" | ForEach {
>>     $_ -match 'ERROR: Opening local file|(ERROR:.+$)' | out-null
>>     $matches[1]
>> }
ERROR: Another error
ERROR: Writing local file  (I want to be alerted to this)
PS C:\>
```

Again, the beauty of this technique is it's easily expandable:
`'Exception1|Exception2|Exception3|(Desired Match)'`